# Question regarding static class under namespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, namespaces

I have a namespacein my JavaScript code "MyNameSpace". I am creating a static JavaScript class "MyChildStaticClass" in it. I am using Modular pattern. Below is my code:

```
if (typeof MyNameSpace == 'undefined' || !MyNameSpace) {

    var MyNameSpace = {};
}

    var MyNameSpace = (function(MyNameSpace) {

        MyNameSpace.MyChildStaticClass = (function() {
            var myobject;
            myobject = { 
                x:function(str) {
                    alert(str);
                }
            };

            return myobject;
        })();
        return MyNameSpace;
    } (MyNameSpace || {}));
```

The above code will be used like:

```
MyNameSpace.MyChildStaticClass.x('test');
```

and the output of above will be an alert box with message test. I have the question that is this a good way of creating a static class and calling methods like the above? Is there any other ways to write it in proficient manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would get the same functionality by doing:

```
var MyNameSpace = {};
MyNameSpace.MyChildStaticClass = {
    x : function(str) {
        alert(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: that is not true. Using your pattern here would not closure the inner methods and therefore they would be accessible from everywhere.

Comment: You are absolutely right about that. I'll just say this for my pattern though: it is readable :)